# setattribute in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code to dynamically set the `onclick` attribute to links, but without me clicking the links itself, the alert is triggered.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
        elm = links[i];
        elm.setAttribute("onclick", alert("you clicked a lik"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the corresponding line to:

```
elm.setAttribute("onclick", function() { alert("you clicked a link");});
```

If you pass as argument a function call (such as `alert('msg')`), the function is executed imediatley and the actual passed argument is the function's return value. All you have to do is wrap your eventHandler code into an anonymous function.
Also, you can declare a function that handles your event and send it's name as argument :

```
function handleClick() { alert("you clicked a link");}
elm.setAttribute("onclick", handleClick);
```

P.S. : I recommend using the `addEventListener` functionality instead of plain old onEvent inline attributes :

```
elm.addEventListener('click', function() { alert("you clicked a link");}, false);
```

Comment: Have to be careful clicking those _liks_, catch them at the wrong angle you'll get a right wetting.

Comment: yeah, funny. that's what copy-paste does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the alert statement into an anonimous function

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        links[i].setAttribute("onclick", function () {
            alert("you clicked a link");
        });
    }
}
```